# Слетает подключение к гипервизору

Tags: windows, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2

У меня есть физический сервер на и через VMware созданы из него же 2 виртуальные машины c Windows Server 2008 R2. Настроил, подключил, все работает, но спустя время я не могу подключится именно к клиенту VMware. Т.е. через удалённый раб стол я могу зайти на любую из виртуальных машин, а подключиться к серверу не могу. Единственный вариант заново возобновить доступ, пропинговать айпишник, 1 попытка Failed,  2 ОК. И после этого я смогу зайти в VMware. Кто сможет помочь, есть у кого варианты?